# How to DROP a table which has constraints, without dropping child tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-key-relationship

I have 60 tables, and I want to DROP 10 of those tables. But while dropping these 10 it is showing FK constraint error. Is there any way to DROP these tables without dropping other tables by disabling constraints?

I have truncate all the data from referred table also, still its showing FK constraint error.

My aim is to DROP a table without DROPPING other tables which are FK to these tables.

Comment: You don't need to drop the "other" tables - you just need to drop the **foreign key constraints** that exist to your table you want to drop

Comment: My table is being refferd as FK by many tables, so do i need to drop foregin key constraints of all those tables??

Comment: Yes you do need to do this. Check out my response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this SQL statement, you can list all FK constraints that reference a given table - and I also provide the SQL command to drop that FK constraint that is referencing your 
table:

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME
SET @TableName = 'dbo.YourTableNameHere'

;WITH ReferencingFK AS 
(
    SELECT 
        fk.Name AS 'FKName',
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.parent_object_id) 'ParentTable',
        cpa.name 'ParentColumnName',
        OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id) 'ReferencedTable',
        cref.name 'ReferencedColumnName'
    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys fk
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns cpa ON fkc.parent_object_id = cpa.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = cpa.column_id
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.columns cref ON fkc.referenced_object_id = cref.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cref.column_id
)
SELECT 
    FKName,
    ParentTable,
    ParentColumnName,
    ReferencedTable,
    ReferencedColumnName,
    DropCmd = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.' + ParentTable + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [' + FKName + ']'
FROM 
    ReferencingFK
WHERE
    ReferencedTable = @TableName
ORDER BY 
    ParentTable, ReferencedTable, FKName
```

So put in one of your 10 tables you want to drop into the `@TableName` variable and run this. You should get an output showing all the FK constraints that reference that table, including a column that has an `ALTER TABLE .... DROP CONSTRAINT ....` command to drop that constraints (**just** the constraint! Not the other table) from the system.